# Control "ws2811" addressable rgb led strip with esp32

Tags: esp32, led

I have bought an addressable RGB Led Strip from [banggood](https://www.banggood.com/4M-WS2811-IC-SMD5050-Dream-Color-RGB-Non-Waterproof-LED-Strip-Light-Individual-Addressable-DC12V-p-1141631.html?rmmds=search&ID=224&cur_warehouse=CN). It was titled as an ws2811 RGB Led Strip. But I only have found ws2811 RGB Leds which aren't Strip, but [LEDs connected with some wire](https://www.banggood.com/de/5M-WS2811-RGB-IP68-Full-Color-50PCS-Bulbs-LED-Pixel-Module-Strip-Light-with-3keys-Controller-DC5V-p-1346213.html?gmcCountry=CH&currency=CHF&cur_warehouse=CN&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_bgs&utm_content=xibei&utm_campaign=xibei-pla-CH-rm-all-0909-pc-20sc&ad_id=462865761528&gclid=Cj0KCQjwt4X8BRCPARIsABmcnOovuTZltuIs__edPZmfMGpqRPUm-4ez_MRQS-oRG7x0BTqFQlsLCicaAtK0EALw_wcB).  I have some doubt that these are ws2811 LEDs. I think they are ws2812 LEDs titled as ws2811s. Now I try to control them with my ESP32 with the [FastLED](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED) library but it does not want to work...

Here is my code:

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#define LED_PIN     27
#define LED_COUNT    1
CRGB leds[LED_COUNT];

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN, RGB>(leds, LED_COUNT);
}

void loop() {
  leds[0] = CRGB(255, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
}
```

Here is my wiring:
[image: My Wiring. Sorry for the catastrophic drawing...]

My problem is that it does not want to work!

Has anyone an idea why?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The esp 32 if I'm correct outputs 3.3V signal. The minimum voltage for WS2811 signal input is 5V. So you will need to use transistor to step up the voltage. I tried it but it didn't work, perhaps i choose the wrong transistor but it was the only one i had available that is PNP. Also please respond if you find the solution. :)

Comment: I've used NPN (or a FET) for this task. I've not tried with the WS2811 yet (I'm here looking for libraries I can use with Espressif).
if using an NPN as a typical inverter setup then you'll need to negate your output. Also watch for RC delay. Maybe a proper push pull level shifter would be best.